# C++ cin input to file

Tags: c++

im learning C++ from a C background.

What i want to do is copy the console input to a file. For this proupouse i do this:

```
 #include "stdafx.h"
 #include <fstream>
 #include <iostream>
 using namespace std;
 int main()
 {
     ofstream file_out;
     file_out.open("test.txt");
     char char_input;
     while (!cin.eof())
     {
         cin.get(char_input);
         file_out << char_input;
     } 
     file_out.close();
     return 0;
}
```

The thing is that works right execpt that the last line isn't in the output file.
I.E: if i enter

```
Hello
My Name Is
Lucas
Goodbye!
```

The "Goodbye" doesn't appear in the file only

```
Hello
My Name Is
Lucas
```

Thxs in advance.

Comment: Don't use `cin.eof()`. Use `cin.get()` as loop condition.

Comment: Use `getline(cin, line)`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is “while ( !feof (file) )” always wrong?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/why-is-while-feof-file-always-wrong)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is usually an anti-pattern (even in C):

```
while (!cin.eof())
```

There are a couple of issues with this. If there is an error you go into an infinite loop (reading characters though we can discount this).

But the main problem is that EOF is only detected after the fact:

```
cin.get(char_input);
// What happens if the EOF just happend.
file_out << char_input;
// You just wrote a random character to the output file.
```

You need to check for it after a read operation, not before.  Always test that the read worked before writing it to the output.

```
// Test the read worked as part of the loop.
// Note: The return type of get() is the stream.
//       When used in a boolean context the stream is converted
//       to bool by using good() which will be true as long as
//       the last read worked.
while (cin.get(char_input)) {
    file_out << char_input;
}
```

I would note this is probably not the most efficient way to read input or write output.

Comment: I tought the the question was solved with the code in the reply, but still gives me the same error.